# Projecting a 3D model in Unity to a raw Image texture

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I currently have a WebCamera that captures video and recognizes the surface of a book and estimates the homography with OpenCV.
(I followed the tutorial at https://bitesofcode.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/augmented-reality-with-python-and-opencv-part-1/ 
and I rewrote the first part for Unity).

Now I'm wondering how would I go about projecting a 3D model in Unity to the raw image?
I am a total newbie in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Camera` (that obviously is directed to your object) which is rendered onto a `RenderTexture`.
[image: Configuration of the Camera]

Then add a `RawImage` to your UI and set the reference to your `RenderTexture`
[image: Configuration of the RawImage]

Comment: The problem I have is probably more Unity specific. I calculated the projection matrix I would need to project a 3D model to the raw image, where  I display the video from the camera, but I don't know how to get the 3D model and apply the projection matrix on it.